# UTF 8 and Doctrine Full text search

Tags: php, utf-8, symfony1, doctrine

After I try to include Searchable in my schema in Symfony. I notice the generator automatic generate the indextable.

But inside the indextable, I see that keywords are being held without any UTF8 Character

ex. Nghĩa -> ngha

Could this affect the search method from doctrine? Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Have you set up encoding in the [databases.yml](http://www.symfonyreference.com/databases-yml) file?

There is an encoding parameter:

```
encoding: utf8
```

Maybe this will solve your problem...

Also in the [schema.yml](http://www.symfonyreference.com/schema-yml#charset-92) file you have an option for charset.

Comment: in all my database model I have configured to have UTF8 collation. The schema probably doesn't replated to this problem since I try to rebuild Index from the start and problem still persisted. words without UTF are indexed correctly while words that have characters with UTF8, those character are just trimmed off the word. There's no point of indexing like this.